# Clear Laravel Queue Cache without restarting

Tags: php, laravel, web

In my application, every customer has a kind of complex class in which we do some search and replaces for that specific customer. I run Queue workers to run a daily sync with eBay for every single customer to do some kind of search and replaces.

The problem is Laravel queues caches the code for a good deal of time and if I want to go and change any customer class file (Which happens frequently), I will have to restart queue workers (Which may stop a running job that I don't intend to stop).

So my question is, how to force Laravel Queue to reread the new code without restarting workers?

Comment: what do you mean by `new code` ?

Comment: I mean the modified code. I want laravel to read any modifications take place in the customers files.

Comment: So you want to change the code in productive system by runtime without laravel getting any error?

Answer (score 8):

you will have not cache if you use code:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Also, interest command:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=system,hot,default --tries=10 --timeout=10  --stop-when-empty
```

Answer (score 6):

Open an extra terminal and use the artisan command

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Answer (score 4):

**This command will instruct all queue workers to gracefully "die" after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost.**

You may gracefully restart all of the workers by issuing the queue:restart command:

`php artisan queue:restart`

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

so the full chain of commands should be (maybe) this:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan queue:restart
```

I left out the config cache command *on purpose* because I don't want to run it initially. Running it, will actually start to cache your config file afaik so I dont want that.

I'm answering because I want to store my own answer to evernote, to never ever have to deal with that bs again