# How to stop Laravel Queues from caching everything?

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-8

The documentation doesn't seem to be quite updated yet, and the answers on the net are mostly wrong, but if you want to have a 'dev' version of a queue worker/processor/listener, then use the 'queue:listen' option instead of the 'queue:work' option.

'queue:work' will absolutely cache everything, and nothing in the world save for killing the process and restarting it will prevent it from caching. that includes using the 'none' cache driver, etc.

This includes using the 'queue:restart' option, which is supposed to soft-restart the worker queue. Maybe it does that, but it doesn't kill the cache.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what sort of things it's caching that you want to kill off?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336301/3532758

Comment: ^ The above linked question and answer were not nearly as clear as this one and also found this one better for my search.

Answer (score 2):

Use `php artisan queue:listen` instead of `php artisan queue:work`.